# Not able to make ajax request when uses IP address instead of localhost

Tags: django

I developed Django based web application in my company which I was able to access at localhost:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/olx
```

and made the ajax request without fail. When I accessed the same on my computer's IP address:

```
http://10.0.100.148:8000/olx
```

, all things were working except ajax reuquest. I got the following error message:

```
403 forbidden
```

Later I did the same thing in my personal laptop at my home and saw that I was able to access ajax request as well in both the cases: localhost and my laptop's IP address:

```
http://192.168.1.8:8000/olx
```

, which was connected to a wifi network. I also accessed the application in my mobile,connected to the same wifi-network, by typing the laptop's IP address and it was working fine.

Now I am in confusion that why I was not able to make the ajax request at the IP address of my company's computer.

What went wrong.

Can somebody help me to understand the reason behind this?

Comment: I found the reson behind this and resolved the above mentioned problem.

Comment: pasted both my system's IP address and localhost address In the Advance setting under LAN setting.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check django logs, anything more than a 403? Could it be an authentication issue?

If you happen to have `DEBUG = False` then make sure the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` variable in settings has all the IP-s you listed.

Comment: Yes I am using ALLOWED_HOSTS =[ ] variable and registered my host. That is why I am able to access the application.